# Transformar esse menu em sub-menus?

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho esse menu vertical:

```
<!-- Coluna2 -->
            <div id="d2" align="right">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <ul id="menu-nav">
                        <li><a href="cEmpresa.html">Hotel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cFuncionarios.html">Funcionários</a</li>
                        <li><a href="cQuartos.html">Quartos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reservas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fechamento</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Seu CSS:

```
/* COLUNA2*/
#d2
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(64, 118, 182, .3);
    margin-top: -10px;
    height: 110%;
    background-color: rgba(64, 118, 182, .5);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Como faço para colocar sub-menus nele? Exemplo, quero dividir esses itens dele em apenas duas categorias, `Administração` e `Sistema` e separar esses itens entre essas duas novas categorias. Exemplo:

```
Administração
    Funcionários
    Hotel
    Relatórios

Sistema
    Clientes
    Produtos
    Reservas
```

Como faço isso da maneira mais simples? Queria exibir apenas as duas categorias (administração e Sistema) daí ao clicar nela ou dar um `hover`, ele exibir suas sub categorias..

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui:
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3464/criando-um-menu-vertical-dropdown-com-css-e-html.aspx Acho que é a isso que tu se refere

Comment: Muito antigamente eu fiz este menu : http://jsfiddle.net/lautert/7t2Dq/6/

Comment: Vou publicar a resposta que achei mais simples e mais adequada, sem usar JavaScript etc, eu só tinha esquecido como aplicar transformações em outro objeto usando o CSS, agora sei que é com o sina de maior >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhei outro exemplo na internet e no CSS, acabei vendo o que eu tinha esquecido, que é o sinal `>` que é para indicar o que mudar em um objeto quando á uma ação em outro objeto. Ficou assim:

**Menu HTML**

```
<nav id="menu">
<ul id="menu-nav">
    <hr id="linha" />
    <li id="opc"><a href="#">Administração</a>
        <ul id="sub">
            <hr/>
            <li><a href="Feedbacks.html">Feedbacks</a></li>
            <li><a href="cFuncionarios.html">Funcionários</a></li>
            <li><a href="cEmpresa.html">Hotel</a></li>
            <li><a href="Relatorios.html">Relatórios</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <br/>
    <hr id="linha" />
    <br/>
    <li id="opc"><a href="#">Sistema</a>
        <ul id="sub">
            <hr/>
            <li><a href="cCheckOut.html">CheckOut</a></li>
            <li><a href="cCliente.html">Clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="cProdutos.html">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="cQuartos.html">Quartos</a></li>
            <li><a href="cReservas.html">Reservas</a></li>
            <li><a href="cServicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <hr id="linha" />
</ul>
</nav>
```

**No CSS**

```
/* MENU*/
nav#menu
{
    margin-top: -20px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#menu-nav li
{
    list-style: none;
    display: run-in;
}


#sub
{
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: none;
}
#sub a
{
    height: 50px;
    color: azure;
}

#menu-nav li:hover > #sub
{
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}

#sub a:hover
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
#menu-nav li a
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#opc a:hover
{
     border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```